# HTML element input type with text formatting options in Bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, text, formatting

I want to have any input textarea where users can enter text and format it i.e I want options like to make it bold, underline.

Is there any inbuilt type for that in bootstrap?

If its not, what other options do I have to achieve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

http://www.tinymce.com/index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><!-- CDN hosted by Cachefly -->
<script src="//tinymce.cachefly.net/4.1/tinymce.min.js"></script>
<script>
        tinymce.init({selector:'textarea'});
</script>
</head>
<body>
        <textarea>Your content here.</textarea>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use contenteditable to accomplish that. Just use a normal div or p with the contenteditable, like Your text here

This will allow you to use formated text.